# Autogenerate REST endpoints from .proto

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I am having problem with compiling the .proto file. Looking to generate REST endpoints from the .proto files. Below is the code and error : 
syntax = "proto3";

```
package pb;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/api/annotations.proto";

service UrlShortener {
  rpc Hello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);

  rpc Encrypt(EncryptRequest) returns (EncryptResponse);

  rpc Decrypt(DecryptRequest) returns (DecryptResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
                get: "/{hash}"
            };
  }
}

message HelloRequest {
  string Name = 1;
}

message HelloResponse {
  string Message = 1;
}

message EncryptRequest {
  string OriginalUrl = 1;
}

message EncryptResponse {
  UrlMap ResponseMap = 1;
}

message DecryptRequest {
  string hash = 1;
}
```

Error : 
github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis: warning: directory does not exist.
google/api/annotations.proto: File not found.
urlshortener.proto: Import "google/api/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors.

Please help with fixing this.

I tried : go get -u github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway
But it failed saying : no buildable go source files in path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have more than one errors in your definition

You are missing the syntax version at the very beginning of your definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";
```

There are some undefined types

```
service.proto:32:3: "UrlMap" is not defined.
service.proto:12:40: "DecryptResponse" is not defined.
```

You are importing and unused empty.proto

You can use the googleapies from

```
{GOPATH}/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis
```

Then run using:

```
protoc -I${GOPATH}/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis -I/usr/local/include -I. service.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:.
```

I made the previous changes and it compiles, so I have the service.pb.go file

**Edited:**

Take a look of this grpc-gateway, maybe can help you
https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway

Comment: syntax  = "proto3"; is present in my file, jus got left in the code block above, same for UrlMap struct as well. Apologies for the pasting unedited version. I found out that the problem is that google/api/annotations has moved from the earlier path grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis. Doing the following resolved the error : go get -u github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/...

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution : The problem is that google/api/annotations has moved from the earlier path grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis to https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/tree/master/third_party/googleapis/google/api.

Running the following resolved the error : go get -u github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/...